# Leaflet setstyle updates work in console but not in file

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have about 1000 polygons I'm load onto a map and I'm trying to color them based on a properties value. I have the code below which produces the following results.

```
mapLayerFieldGrid = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/../static/data/fields/field001.geojson", {style: styleFieldGrid});

mapLayerFieldGrid.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if(layer.feature.properties.health == 1) {
      layer.setStyle({fillColor: plantHealth1});
    } else if(layer.feature.properties.health == 2) {
      layer.setStyle({fillColor: plantHealth2});
    } else if(layer.feature.properties.health == 3) {
      layer.setStyle({fillColor: plantHealth3});
    } else if(layer.feature.properties.health == 4) {
      layer.setStyle({fillColor: plantHealth4});
    } else if(layer.feature.properties.health == 5) {
    layer.setStyle({fillColor: plantHealth5});
    }
});


mapLayerFieldGrid.addTo(mapField);
```

[image]

The polygons are there but they aren't colored correctly. When I run the eachLayer function in the console I do get the right result, which looks like this.

[image]

So my question is why does this work in the console, but not when the page loads, and how do I correct this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first "A" in "AJAX" is for [*Asynchronous*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

After you instantiate your `new L.GeoJSON.AJAX`, you have a Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group in your `mapLayerFieldGrid` variable, but it is still empty. [Leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) needs some time to fetch your GeoJSON data from the network (even locally). During this time, the rest of your script continues execution, so `mapLayerFieldGrid.eachLayer` works on an empty array of layers.

When you perform code execution in your console, leaflet-ajax had already time to retrieve your GeoJSON data and to fill your `mapLayerFieldGrid` layer group, so now `mapLayerFieldGrid.eachLayer` works on a non-empty array of layers.

You could either:

1. Listen to the `"data:loaded"` event and execute your code in the event listener callback
2. Perform the re-styling *directly* in the [`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson-style) option of the `L.geoJSON` factory (same for `L.GeoJSON.AJAX`), since you already use it.

In more details:

1. Using the `"data:loaded"` event of `L.GeoJSON.AJAX`:

```js
var mapLayerFieldGrid = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(url, options).on("data:loaded", function () {
  mapLayerFieldGrid.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    // Perform some operations, re-styling, etc.
  });
});
```

2. Using the `style` option: simply get some inspiration from the [Leaflet choropleth map tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/#adding-some-color):

```js
new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(url, {
  style: style
}).addTo(mapField);

function getColor(d) {
  return d === 1 ? plantHealth1 :
    d === 2 ? plantHealth2 :
    d === 3 ? plantHealth3 :
    d === 4 ? plantHealth4 :
    d === 5 ? plantHealth5 :
    defaultColor;
}

function style(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.health),
    // Whatever values in your styleFieldGrid style.
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  };
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was one of the most detailed responses I've ever seen, Thank you very much for the help!